# Is it possible for me to get a review of my language?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm currently designing a stack-based language intended for scripting. I'm wondering if it's possible for me to have its syntax evaluated by this community, e.g., I'd describe the language and how it works, and then receive feedback concerning the improvement of code readability.

E.g., this is a variable declaration in my language:

```
i 5 <-
```

Someone may respond:

> Variable declaration is a bit awkward. I think it would be more readable if variable declaration was something like `<value> <reference> <-`.

Would this be an appropriate format for this site?

Comment: Can you clarify if your language is an actual working implementation, e.g. does it compile and work correctly?

Comment: @Phrancis It's in development, but has a working (unpublished) interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you're still at the design stage; feedback like you describe would inherently be opinion-based - and IMO very likely closed as such.

It might be possible to formulate your question in such a way that it can be answered on [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) (see the [language-design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design) tag).

Once you've formally specified your language, implemented the specs in the language of your choice to make a lexer, parser, interpreter, and/or compiler, *then* you'll definitely have something we can review and potentially improve.

And once you have an interpreter (compiler?) that reviewers can use to write and run code written in that language, you can post the very first [your-language-here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/your-language-here)[fizzbuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) question!

But discussing language design? A chatroom would probably be a better suited place for it.

Comment: So I'd ask you guys here to review the source code of the interpreter, once implemented?

Comment: Absolutely! Pretty sure it's been done before. Well, it's been done multiple times over with [tag:brainfuck] anyway ;-)